# Deducing the function return type from its parameter's return type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, c++03

I have the code below

```
template<typename U, typename F >
U GetListAndSearchName( F listGetter, const std::string& stringName )
{
    std::vector<UserType> newList;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
    {
        const std::vector<U>& list = listGetter(myList[i]);
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ )
        {
            if ( list[i]->GetName() == stringName )
                return list[i];
        }
    }
    return U();
}
```

Even U exists in my function pointer's return type which is template parameter F(I am using std::mem_fn to create it later F might be std::function as well ) currently I am needing to explicitly pass U's type to compiler.

How can I have my old Vs2010 compiler to deduce U's type ?

Comment: You can't.  Return types are not deducible by themselves.

Comment: I've wacked in a specific standard tag. I'm not sure this is easily solvable in C++03.

Comment: You can't in c++03, you could probably in C++14 with `decltype(auto)`

Comment: Look for function_traits.

Comment: @101010 Maybe you can write it as answer if you have time. Even not useful for me it might be someone else's answer.

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir: From C++11 onwards you can use a trailing return type syntax. There will be very many duplicates out there. An answer on those lines for this question would be downvoted.

Comment: @Bathsheba Since MSVS 2010 [supports trailing return types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) should this just be closed to one of those dupes?

Comment: @Bathsheba Why would it be downvoted? VS2010 supports both trailing return types and `decltype`.

Comment: @Angew: On that basis it wouldn't be. I've upvoted the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works in 2010:

```
template<typename F>
auto GetListAndSearchName (F listGetter, const std::string& stringName) 
  -> decltype(listGetter(myList[0])[0])
```

Comment: Nice. Gets round the `::` problem.

Comment: What happens if the lists empty

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir The expression inside `decltype` is not evaluated, so nothing bad happens.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use decltype and trailing return types. They are both C++11 features, but according to MSDN they should be supported by Visual Studio 2010. You need also a type trait to extract value_type from vector.

```
template<typename T>
struct value_type { typedef T::value_type type; };

template<typename F>
auto GetListAndSearchName( F listGetter, const std::string& stringName )
    -> typename value_type<decltype(listGetter(myList[0]))>::type
```

Comment: It's correct in principle, but to get around VS2010's limitations on `decltype`, you might need a separate trait to extract `element_type`. I believe it doesn't like using `::` with `decltype` as the LHS operator.